# checking active $state in switch statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

in Angular I want to return a `header.tpl.html` given a loaded page is not a given `$state`. Seems like the easiest way would be a switch statement. In this case, I want to return the `header.tpl.html` if the current state is not states 1,2, or 3.

What is the correct value to plug in for `expression`? Also, are there better ways to check for the current state?

```
  $scope.menuRender = function () {
      switch (expression) {
        case $state.is('state1'):
        return;
        break;
      switch
        case $state.is('state2'):
        return;
        break;
      switch 
        case $state.is('state3'):
        return;
        break;
      default:
        return "header.tpl.html";
      }
  };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reiterate the switch command, and you don't need to break after you return. Use break to break out of the switch if you want to keep processing the code below the switch statement, otherwise you can safely just return a value.

```
$scope.menuRender = function () {
  switch ($state) {
    case ('state1'):
      return 'header-alt1.tpl.html';

    case ('state2'):
      return 'header-alt2.tpl.html';

    //...etc...

    default:
      return "header.tpl.html";
  }
```

};

Comment: What's happening here, in this case, is ```switch``` is just checking properties on the ```$state```?

Comment: Each switch-case is identical to an "if ($state = 'state1') {}" statement. I don't know what information your $state contains. You will probably need to modify it to fit your needs. This is more a pseudocode answer than something you can just copy/paste.

Comment: Got it. Great direction. Thank you!

Comment: The = sign should be == in my post above.